# Trying to get my curcuit board running

Tags: wiring, breadboard, pi-zero-w-2

I am trying to create a curcuit board for a project of mine.
Several devices are connected to a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W. One of them is not working via the curcuit board but directly connected to a Raspberry Pi. So I think I have an issue with the curcuit board design.

Here you can see the cucuit board:

[image: Curcuit Board]

[image]

**Question**: What do I need to do in order to get the 4 Relay running so that I can activate the D2FS switches?

On the curcuit board I have two D2FS Switches running. They are supposed to be activated by a 4 Relay Module. If the Relay is directly attached to the Raspberry Pi, it works as it should. As soon as I connect it via the curcuit board, the Relay does not react at all.
The D2FS switches are marked as D2FS1 and D2FS2 and the Relay is marked as "Relay".

[Link to 4-Relay](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01BAFLMCI/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

[Link to D2F Microswitch](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07XLW8D1X/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1638&creative=6742&creativeASIN=B07XLW8D1X&linkCode=as2&tag=sveebo-21&linkId=edd51250352fc58301fb5020dcc315c6)

[Example for external Power Supply with galvanic isolation](https://www.kollino.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Relaiskarte_option3.png)

[image: 4-Relay Module]

[image: Delay Schematics]

[image: Relay Schematics]

[image: D2F Switch]

[image: D2F Schematics]

Here you can see the breadboard version:
[image: 4-Releay Module]

***Important notice***: I am not using the "Relay" pin of the D2FS switches that are going to the IN1 and IN2 of the Relay on the curcuit board.
I have connected the VCC and GND from the curcuit board to the 4-Relay Module and the "pi" pins of the D2FS1 and D2FS2 to the S1 and S2 Switch directly as the S1 and S2 are connected to the 4-Relay Module.

I (de)activate the switches with the following commands:

```
/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 23 out
/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 20 out
/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 23 1 <or> 0
/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 20 1 <or> 0
```

Comment: Can you post a schematic, your frizzy picture leaves a lot to be desired. Also post links to the hardware devices showing "technical" not sales information.

Comment: I have added the provided information. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Did you run DRC on your board? I see a couple places where the conductor spacing is unnecessarily small, possibly causing shorts on your board.

Comment: Yes, I did. It was all successful.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying very hard and I appreciate that. From what I can see your design is good. You show your board, is that the schematic for it below. The schematic print is so small and fuzzy that I can't blow it up enough to read. Same problem with the relay board. At this point I am going to point at the relay module, it is a 5V module and you are signaling it with a 3V3 signal. Are you also powering it from 3V3? If so that will not work properly. From what I can see the possible lower threshold for the input to the relay is about 3V2 but this will change some with temperature etc. They have a LED in series with the opto LED so add those two forward voltages together then subtract that from the 3V3 and you have nothing left to generate current flow in the opto isolator. I do not the Vf of the opto isolators etc. I believe you will need a level shifter. You can also use a 74HCT device to do that, run it on 5V. One of the reasons I ask for links to the hardware devices is to check things like this out. There is no information I see that states it will work with a 3V3 input. I looked and found a similar on azon that said RP compatible, it was 5V and I very much doubt it. The schematic shows what is powering what etc. Do not give up you will get a lot from this in the end. Do you have a multimeter of some type?

From your relay link to azon there was no schematic or other technical information. From that I was able to find several I believe similar schematics, none of them were very clear but they had LEDs or diode in series with the input of the optocoupler.  I am assuming the switches are OK. Be sure all the grounds are connected and power the relays from the external 5V power supply.

At this point we will have to make some voltage measurements.  Important, all grounds must be connected. Connect the black (-) of the meter to ground and set for 5V to be about mid to 80% of the display range, do this for all measurements.  Be sure you are on DC voltage. Check to verify the board turns on with a + input.

Test: power the relay board with 5V. Turn on all of the relays (first with 5V then 3.2V at the input pin)  then measure the input pin to the relay board. Is it at least 3.0V? Measure both sides of the relay diode, one side should be about 0.7 and the other 5V. The first confirms the relay module is told to turn on, the second verifies the on-board transistor turned the relay on and the “relay LEDs”. You will do this twice once with 3V input then with a 5V input. You will also notice the "relay LEDs" will be brighter with 5V input.  If any of this tests fail the relay board is bad.

If this passes then write some code to cause all of the pins to turn on with the Pi and repeat the test. Let us know how you do.

Comment: Thank you Gil, I am sorry for the poor Quality. I have added a Link for the 4-Releay and the Micro Switch. Where do you see that the Signal is 3V3? The Relay itself is currently powered over a 5V Pin of the Raspberry Pi. Another Option could be, as the VCC for the LED Strings is currently an external 5V Power Supply, that I add a connection from that Power-Supply to the Relay, if that helps. Here is an example with galvanic isolation of which I have added a link as well.

Comment: Sorry I could not read the schematic it was all fuzzy.